# Java 8 Stateful consumer

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is conditional composition of Consumers possible in Java 8? Basically I'm looking to create a custom Lambda interface similar to Consumer but that only works with one type of object. Let's call it, `Stateful` and it contains multiple statuses (we'll say two for the purpose of this example):

```
public class Stateful {
   private int status1;
   private int status2;
}
```

We have a lot of areas in our code where we do an operation on a Stateful and, if the status has changed, we would do another operation. I was wondering if we could use composition to handle this in a more compact and elegant manner. Right now we would do something like:

```
SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> oldStates = new SimpleEntry(stateful.getStatus1(), stateful.getStatus2());

applyLogicOnStateful(stateful); //do some operation that may change state values
if(isStatusChanged(oldStates, stateful) { //compare oldStates integers to status integers
    doSomethingElse(stateful);
}
```

where I think something like this would look better:

```
statefulConsumer
.accept((stateful)->applyLogicOnStateful(stateful))
.ifStatusChanged((stateful)->doSomethingElse(stateful));
```

but I don't know if we would be able to track the change in status from before the first consumer to after. Maybe I need to create a lambda that takes two consumers as input?

I'm definitely looking to do this without the assistance of a 3rd party library, although you're welcome to promote one here if it is helpful.

Comment: The "compact and elegant" way to do this is in your first example, using a perfectly normal, readable `if` statement.

Comment: I respectfully disagree: having to save the state to a variable, do some logic, and then do the comparison is bulky and definitely not DRY. I suppose I could have a modified consumer that returns a boolean if the status changes, though.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is if your applyLogicOnStateful return a boolean if your status change or if you build a Predicate with the expected values before calling all your operations (which is the same of what you are doing now, just more elegant)

Comment: You don't really gain anything by using lambdas here and it makes debugging more difficult. You'd be better off just making a helper method that does `applyLogicOnStateful` and returns a boolean from `isStatusChanged`. Then you can do `if (applyLogic(...)) doSomething(...);`.

Comment: “*having to save the state to a variable, do some logic, and then do the comparison is bulky and definitely not DRY*”. Sure, but that’s the design mistake made when defining the methods `applyLogicOnStateful` and `isStatusChanged` the way they are. Nothing you build around it, be it lambda expression related or not, can change that design flaw. You can try to hide it inside another method, but that’s again not an issue of using lambda expression or not.

Comment: I realized a made a big mistake transcribing this question: `isStatusChanged` would need to take the oldStates variable as a parameter in addition to the stateful instance. I'll make an edit to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will return a `Consumer<Stateful>` that will extract the former state, do the change, compare results, and conditionally operate on the changed object.

```
public static Consumer<Stateful> getStatefulConsumer(
        Function<Stateful,SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer>> getStatus,                  // extract status from Stateful
        Consumer<Stateful> applyLogic,                                              // apply business logic
        BiPredicate<SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer>,SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer>> compareState, // test statuses for change
        Consumer<Stateful> onChange)                                                // doSomethingElse
{
    return stateful -> {
        SimpleEntry<Integer,Integer> oldStatus = getStatus.apply(stateful);
        applyLogic.accept(stateful);
        if(!compareState.test(oldStatus, getStatus.apply(stateful))){
            onChange.accept(stateful);
        }   
    };
}
```

You might use it like this:

```
Consumer<Stateful> ifChanged = getStatefulConsumer(s -> new SimpleEntry<> ( s.status1, s.status2 ), 
    s -> changeSomething(s), Objects::equals, s->doSomething(s));
```

You could generify the extracted status so that different stateful types could have different extracted status types, or even use Stateful::clone to copy the status.

Comment: Thanks Hank- I actually made a mistake in outlining the `statusChanged` method as it needs the old state information to make that determination. I'll edit my original question to reflect that and my apologies for the confusion

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer to take your feedback into account.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: One advantage of returning it as a `Consumer<Stateful>` is that you can use it in various APIs such as `Stream.forEach()`, `Collection.forEach()`, `Optional.ifPresent`, `CompletableFuture.thenAccept()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am working with right now is to create a Lambda interface that takes the Stateful instance and two Consumers as input:

```
public interface StatefulConsumer {
    void accept(Stateful stateful, Consumer<Stateful> consumer, Consumer<Stateful> ifStateChangedConsumer);
}
```

and an implementation:

```
final StatefulConsumer IfStateChanges = new StatefulConsumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Stateful stateful, Consumer<Stateful> consumer, Consumer<Stateful> ifStateChangedConsumer) {
        SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> oldStates = new SimpleEntry(stateful.getStatus1(), stateful.getStatus2());

        consumer.accept(stateful); //do some operation that may change state values
        if(isStatusChanged(oldStates, stateful) { //compare oldStates integers to status integers
            ifStateChangedConsumer.accept(stateful);
        }
    }
};
```

which could be called like this:
IfStateChanges.accept(stateful,
    (Stateful s)->applyLogicOnStateful(stateful),
    (Stateful s)->doSomethingElse(stateful))

It could also be implemented as a Predicate or a Function that takes a stateful and a consumer as input and returns a boolean for use in an if Statement

Comment: it looks like we ended up on a similar tack.  great minds. :-)